# Looking for a lua obfuscator to protect code

Tags: plugins, lua, obfuscation

I have written a plugin for vanilla lua. I wish to protect this plugin, and I have heard of *obfuscation*. I tried XFuscator, but even after fixing line 5's logic, it doesnt work. Are there any newer, better ones floating out there?

Thanks!

Comment: if you don't find it on via www.google.com and alike there is nothing decent. your post is pretty obsolete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to run your Lua script in the same machine you build it (I mean, same Lua version, same machine architecture), you could just compile it to bytecode using luac like this:

```
luac -s -o example.out example.lua
```

And distribute the .out file, that doesn't contain the Lua source code.

Note that Lua bytecode is **platform specific** (endianness, word size), and it could change in future Lua versions (in fact it already did in the past). For that reason, if you compile it, let's say, in a Intel x86-64 with Lua 5.3, you should run your generated .out only in this kind of machines or compatible ones.